# Problem with run docker from Apache AMI (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I created a web server with apache and php in AWS. Then I created a docker with the AMI from web server.

```
     tar -c -C /mnt/ . | docker import - MY-IMAGE-NAME
```

The image was created:

```
    docker images
    REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED                      SIZE
    workshop            latest              6de90688f964        About a minute ago   1.14GB
```

I ran the docker exposing the port 80

```
     docker run -tid -p 80:80 6de90688f964 /bin/bash
```

But I cant load the web. I used the public IP from the docker server. When I used curl I obtained

```
     root@ip-10-10-0-10:/home/ubuntu# curl 18.206.153.112
     curl: (7) Failed to connect to 18.206.153.112 port 80: Connection refused
```

Could you help me?

Comment: did you check your security group policy (allow 80 inbound) on your instance ? And your NACLs ?

Comment: That is not a normal way to create a Docker image.  The way you’ve invoked it, you’re starting a shell, but not actually running Apache, unless there are more details you haven’t shown.

Comment: What is the normal way? how can run apache? I've only followed steps from a manual. I'm new at this,can you help me with documentation?

Comment: Docker has a good [tutorial on building and running custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/), but just to run Apache I'd run the [prebuilt `httpd` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/).  `docker import` isn't part of the usual Docker workflow at all.

Comment: Thanks, now my container is working. The new problem is created new image after some change on running docker. I gonna create new question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the security policy for this AWS Instance to allow TCP 
inbound traffic on port 80 (EC2 Dashboard --> Security Groups).

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: The port is open, the problem is other.